# How can I cut very frame of a video into several pictures in Android?

Tags: android, video, multimedia

How can I cut a video frame by frame into several areas. Or can I only display 1/n part of the whole view of the video? I mean just like that we have two screen and each one show part of the video but altogether show a whole view of the video? How can I implement it in Android development???
Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Do you mean, for example, displaying the upper left corner of a video on one mobile, the upper right on another mobile, etc so you finally have 4 mobile phones showing the whole video?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that by using FFmpeg I can finish that job.
We can port ffmpeg to Android and use the library provided by ffmpeg. To achieve that goal, use filter/crop